# 32 Bit vs 64 Bit: Massive Runtime Difference

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I am considering the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   unsigned int sum = 0;
   for (unsigned int i = 1; i < std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max(); ++i) {
      double f = static_cast<double>(i);
      unsigned int t = static_cast<unsigned int>(f); 
      sum += (t % 2);
   }
   std::cout << sum << std::endl;
   return 0; 
}
```

I use the gcc / g++ compiler, g++ -v gives gcc version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012] (SUSE Linux).
I am running openSUSE 12.3 (x86_64) and have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU.

Running

```
g++ -O3 test.C -o test_64_opt
g++ -O0 test.C -o test_64_no_opt
g++ -m32 -O3 test.C -o test_32_opt
g++ -m32 -O0 test.C -o test_32_no_opt

time ./test_64_opt
time ./test_64_no_opt
time ./test_32_opt
time ./test_32_no_opt
```

yields

```
2147483647

real    0m4.920s
user    0m4.904s
sys     0m0.001s

2147483647

real    0m16.918s
user    0m16.851s
sys     0m0.019s

2147483647

real    0m37.422s
user    0m37.308s
sys     0m0.000s

2147483647

real    0m57.973s
user    0m57.790s
sys     0m0.011s
```

Using float instead of double, the optimized 64 bit variant even finishes in 2.4 seconds, while the other running times stay roughly the same. However, with float I get different outputs depending on optimization, probably due to the higher processor-internal precision.

I know 64 bit may have faster math, but we have a factor of 7 (and nearly 15 with floats) here.

I would appreciate an explanation of these running time discrepancies.

Comment: Benchmarking is meaningful only when asking the compiler to optimize. I do believe that even in `-m32` the `double` is 8 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't 32bit vs 64bit, it's the lack of SSE and SSE2. When compiling for 64bit, gcc assumes it can use SSE and SSE2 since all available x86_64 processors have it.

Compile your 32bit version with `-msse -msse2` and the runtime difference nearly disappears.

My benchmark results for completeness:

```
-O3 -m32 -msse -msse2     4.678s
-O3 (64bit)               4.524s
```

Comment: For optimal effect, use "-m32 -march=native".

Comment: For optimal effect, use "-m32 -march=native" (sorry for editing max's comment)